# (Wake on Lan?) + Autologon + Autologin as specific user (+ Autostart + Shutdown)

Tags: windows, authentication, wake-on-lan

Hello again everybody,

I already read about wake on lan and how it works, but there is one important question left:

What next?

You can boot the PC via Lan, but how can I make it auto-Login as a specific user?

The goal is:

1. Wake on lan (from complete shutdown)
2. Automatically log in as user X (but ONLY when boot via wake on lan! Otherwise(normal start) the Login-prompt should maintain!)
3. Autostart my script
4. After completion shutdown PC

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can create a scheduled task that gets started when booting up. You don't need to login in order to start your script. After completion you can shutdown the system with "shutdown -s -f -t 0" from within your script.

Comment: Hello Robert, thanks for your answer.
But isn´t there the Problem, that this Task gets executed EVERY time? I mean, even if the "normal" user starts his PC (physical) the Scheduled Task runs, right? That would be wrong